# for loop stops after 3 loops

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

My script works. It saved the first three mail-ids from `mailq` in the temp file, but after that I only get an error.

```
for QID in $(/opt/zimbra/postfix/sbin/mailq | grep -E "^[0-9A-F]{10,12}\ "|cut -f1 -d' '); do
    /opt/zimbra/postfix/sbin/postcat -c /opt/zimbra/postfix/conf -q ${QID}|grep -q '$1' &&
    TEMP=`(mktemp /tmp/$1.XXXX)`
    echo ${QID} >> $TEMP
done

echo "All mail in quene from IP $1 is listed in file: $TEMP"

./test.sh 127.0.0.1

./test.sh: line 1: $TEMP: ambiguous redirect

./test.sh: line 1: $TEMP: ambiguous redirect

./test.sh: line 1: $TEMP: ambiguous redirect

./test.sh: line 1: $TEMP: ambiguous redirect

./test.sh: line 1: $TEMP: ambiguous redirect

./test.sh: line 1: $TEMP: ambiguous redirect
```

All mail in queue from IP 127.0.0.1 is listed in file: `/tmp/127.0.0.1.s7oN`

Comment: Assert your assumptions? I would start with checking the output of `/opt/zimbra/postfix/sbin/mailq | grep -E "^[0-9A-F]{10,12}\ "|cut -f1 -d''` (i.e., what gets looped over), and then work from there...

Comment: That part works, what does not work, is the $TEMP-part.

Comment: Check your script with http://www.shellcheck.net/. There are some essential mistakes inside.

Comment: @user3297323: "...and then work from there."

Comment: At best, the parentheses in `(mktemp...)` are unnecessary.

Comment: agree with @chepner --> it should be TEMP=backquote`mktemp /tmp/$1.XXXX`backquote (no parentheses)